# Issue with sqlite3 pragma_table_info trying to check if column "name" exists

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I created a function in Python that creates columns in tables dynamically from data I'm feeding it:

```
@db_con_func
def create_columns(self, columns: list, table: str):
    '''create_columns creates columns in a table if they do not exist

    Args:
        columns (list): the expected columns
        table (str): the table to check

    Raises:
        ConnectionError: if the database connection could not be established
    '''

    # ensure all columns are lowercase
    columns = list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), columns))

    for column in columns:
        logger.debug("Checking if column %s exists in table %s", column, table)
        # check if column exists
        _ = self.db_cur.execute(f"select count(*) from pragma_table_info(\"{table}\") where name=\"{column}\"")
        # get the first result of the query
        if _.fetchone()[0] == 0:
            logger.debug("Column %s does not exist in table %s", column, table)
            try:
                logger.debug("Adding column %s to table %s", column, table)
                self.db_cur.execute(f"ALTER TABLE '{table}' ADD COLUMN '{column}' TEXT")
                logger.debug("Column %s added to table %s", column, table)
            except sqlite3.Error as err:
                logger.error("Error adding column %s to table %s with error: %s", column, table, err)
                raise ConnectionError(f"Error adding column {column} to table {table} with error: {err}") from err
        else:
            logger.debug("Column %s exists in table %s", column, table)
```

This works except when I check if a column `name` exists I get the count of all columns since `pragma_name_table` uses a column called `name`, so the column `name` is never created. Since it is a dynamic approach I can't predict what the column names would be. Renaming the feeding data isn't an option.

```
sqlite> select * from pragma_table_info("bp_team_members") where name="name";
cid  name           type     notnull  dflt_value  pk
---  -------------  -------  -------  ----------  --
0    id             INTEGER  0                    1 
1    db_created_at  TEXT     1                    0 
2    db_updated_at  TEXT     1                    0 
3    code           TEXT     0                    0 
4    members        TEXT     0                    0
```

How to honor `name="name"`? `select count(*) from pragma_table_info("bp_team_members") where name="name"` should return 0 if no column called `name` exists.